# Cplex Syntax to model a proportion constraint

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, cplex

I am having difficulty with the syntax (and possibly logic) of modelling a proportion constraint in Cplex:

Here is the content of my .dat file:

```
nPaper = 3;
nWoods = 3;

SalesPrice = [60, 75, 40]; 
PurcPrice = [50, 40, 30];
ProdCost = [4, 2.8, 2.8]
Demand = [4000, 3800, 3500];
minWood1 = [0.6, 0.65, 0.3];
minWood2 = [0.3, 0.25, 0.4];
```

and part of the model file:

```
int nPaper =...;
int nWood =...;

range Paper = 1..nPaper;
range Wood = 1..nWood;

float SalesPrice[Paper] =...;
float PurcPrice[Wood] =...;
float ProdCost[Paper] =...;
float Demand[Paper] =...;
float minSteel[Paper] =...;
float minBronze[Paper] =...;

dvar float+ Blend[Wood][Paper];

dexpr float Revenue= sum(j in Paper) SalesPrice[j]*(sum(i in Wood) Blend[i] [j]);
dexpr float PurchaseCost= sum(j in Wood) PurcPrice[j]*(sum(i in Paper) Blend[j][i]);
dexpr float ProductionCost = sum(j in Paper) ProdCost[j]*(sum(i in Wood) Blend[i][j]);
dexpr float Profit = Revenue - PurchaseCost - ProductionCost;

maximize Profit;

subject to {
  forall (j in Paper)
    sum(i in Wood) Blend[i][j]== Demand[j];
```

Problem Constraints: As you can see in the data, there is a minimum Wood value (minWood) for each Paper type that is being produced. The constraint I am trying to add is to specify the minimum proportion for 1 particular wood type (represented in vector minWood1) when mixed with the other two wood types to make paper [j].

In other words, what I've tried to state is: For paper 1, the proportion of wood 1 should be minWood and then also continue to specify other proportions as per the vector.

```
forall (j in Paper)
     sum(i in Wood)minWood1 >= minWood1;

forall (j in Paper)
     sum(i in Wood)minWood2 >= minWood2;}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume that this is a typo:

forall (j in Paper)
    minWood2 >= sum(i in Wood)minWood2;

Comment: Yes, that doesn't make sense does it. I will update. Can you help?

Comment: you should probably have something like for all (j in Paper) Blend[Wood1] >= minWood1 * Demand[j] etc